# SugarCRM silent upgrade doesn't work. Error: This is command-line only script

Tags: command-line, sugarcrm

I've a problem with the sugarcrm silent upgrade process.

After downloading the necessary files I was trying to start the installation process with the following command:

```
php.5 -f /var/www/websites/SUGARCRMSILENT/silentUpgrade.php /var/www/websites/SUGARCRMSILENT/SugarPro-Upgrade-6.5.x-to-6.5.18.zip /var/www/websites/SUGARCRMSILENT/silent.log /var/www/websites/sugarcrm admin
```

`php -f instead of php.5 -f` isn't working, too.

I'll get the following error after executing the command above:

`This is command-line only script`

Here is the upgrade manual: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/02_Sugar_Enterprise/Sugar_Enterprise_6.5/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRons6zPZKXonjHpfsX64%2BstWKW%2FlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4AT8JjI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFT7jMMbVo0LgFXBk%3D#Upgrading?utm_source=sugarcrm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=GLOBAL_Security_Vulnerability_Q314

The command is from: https://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/sugarcrm/silent-upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the file you will find a check something like:

```
$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if (substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) != 'cli') {
    die("This is command-line only script");
}
```

It's likely that `php_sapi_name()` is returning something without `cli` in it. It's *probably* safe to comment out the die and try running the updater but, as always, you should ensure you have a backup of everything before making any changes.

Comment: Yeah. I've already try'd this solution...

This is the new error after outcommenting:
This is command-line only script<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/kunden/261584_20457/webseiten/kunden/SUGARCRMSILENT/silentUpgrade_step2.php</b> on line <b>407</b><br />
***************         silentupgrade failed         ***************: 255

Comment: @abacus It sounds like the silent installation files you have are incorrect. What version are you upgrading to? Where did you get the installer?

Comment: I wanna upgrade from 6.5.14 to 6.5.18.
The files are from https://store.sugarcrm.com/download

Comment: @abacus I'm afraid you'll have to take it up with sugar in that case.

Comment: Thanks! I've opened a new ticket. I'll inform you about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: http://www.random-dev.de/skript-unter-anderer-php-version-aufrufen/

Just change the php version via symlink. After that you can use the command php -f with another php version as normal.